# Область видимости переменной

Tags: android, java

Ребята. Помогите, туплю чего-то с областью видимости переменной. Учу помаленьку программирование под Android. Есть код:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            float num1;
            float num2;
            float result;
            num1 = 1;
            num2 = 2;
            int idBtn = v.getId();
            if (idBtn == R.id.btnPlus) {
                result = num1+num2;
            }
            scrResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        }
```

Делаю просто сложение. Но почему переменная result выходит за область видимости? Выдает такую ошибку **The local variable result may not have been initialized.** Что не так? Написал то же самое на PHP - работает как часы.((

Comment: Проблема решена!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В java переменные класса инициализируются по умолчанию, в то же время локальные переменные не имеют значений по умолчанию. Другими словами, переменная float result, которая будет объявленна в теле класса, получит значение 0.

```
public class Test
{
   float result;
}
```

И её можно будет использовать в теле метода. Когда ты объявляешь переменную в теле метода, ей не присваивается никакое значение, на что и ругается компилятор. Ты можешь объявить её явно, и всё будет работать.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            float num1;
            float num2;
            float result = 0;
            num1 = 1;
            num2 = 2;
            int idBtn = v.getId();
            if (idBtn == R.id.btnPlus) {
                result = num1+num2;
            }
            scrResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        }
```